# video.js Change Src When Seeking Without Resting Playback

Tags: video.js

My video src is an AWS presigned request url, it expires in x amount of time. The video will start playing just fine in video.js. For large video files after the brief url expiration time, changing the seek bar causes a network error because the original src link has expired. How do you refresh the src with another unexpired presigned url without restarting from the beginning of the video? I don't want the video to go back the beginning.

So far I have found that you can capture the change of the seek bar by listening for the event 'timeupdate' and in the passed event testing for e.manuallyTriggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue today. i'm using plyr instead of videojs, so i'm not sure if you can do this exact thing, but my solution was:

1. bind an error handler to the player for when the link has expired and someone tries to play/seek, and then in the handler...
2. store the current time of the video
3. send an ajax request to my server to get an updated signed URL
4. update the source of the player
5. set the current time of the video to the previously stored time

it's kind of slow/clunky, but it's the best fix i could come up with at the moment, aside from loading the entire video before allowing playback (which didn't seem like great UX).

update: this does work with videojs...but it doesn't work with either player in Safari, which apparently doesn't send the error event at all.