# How to change HTML5 video's src without reloading?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, html5-video, pre-signed-url

I want to display videos stored on Amazon S3, but I don't want to make the video files publicly available. To do this I plan to use pre-signed, temporary link URLs with a standard video element. If there is a better way to play auth-protected videos I would be interested to hear it, but the rest of my question is predicated on this approach.

I can refresh the pre-signed URL when it expires, but I can't change the `src` attribute without the video element thinking that I am giving it a whole new video to load. Is there a way to change the `src` but specify that the new URL points to the same video file?

**In case it makes a difference, I only need to change the URL's query string.**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759313/video-js-change-src-when-seeking-without-resting-playback) deals with an almost identical problem but the proposed solution (setting the starting offset time of the video before reloading) is unsatisfactory to me. That still requires reloading the video file and the transition is very noticeable.

Comment: So, confirming... the problem is that you want the video to be available to an individual viewer for a longer period of time than the lifetime of the signed URL... which you don't want to extend, because that increases the potential for unauthorized sharing of the URL.  Is that right?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes that is effectively correct. But no matter how long I make the links last, they will expire eventually. And I have to handle that somehow.

Comment: So is this something like a kiosk/dashboard/marquee application?  Because in a human-interactive environment, you would normally just sign the links when you render the HTML.  CloudFront signed cookies might be useful, depending on the level of granularity you need, since the cookies can give the viewer access to one or more objects, because they can support `*` in the path, but they but are limited to one path pattern.  Or you could roll your own cookie or query-string auth solution with Lambda@Edge and a CloudFront Origin Access Identity. Need a little more detail about the use case.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You know a lot more than me about AWS. I'm pretty much only familiar with S3, RDS, IAM, and Cognito. I would very much appreciate if you post an answer with a CloudFront alternative. The use case is secure storage and browsing of personal media.